# CSS selector if element does NOT have a specific parent element

Tags: css, sass

I want to change the styling of an element if it does not have a certain parent element, without having to overwrite it to it's original value.

See https://jsfiddle.net/xqb2z8tc/
The problem with above code is that it will generate a lot of css as the mixin is used a lot, so we want to rewrite it. I thought of using ':has()' selector (browser support is ok for us) but I cannot figure out how.

Something like the code below but it should work for all cases, see jsfiddle above.

```
.dark-view:not(:has(.obox)) p {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: questions must be self-containing and not relay on external resources such as fiddles. Include enough debugging details in the form of a [repro] that your question is still understandable without a fiddle.

Comment: Can you add `.obox` to all `p`?

Comment: For arbitrary distance between ancestor and descendant this is not possible. But if the distance is fixed, e.g. for direct parent and child, it can be done with `:not(.obox) > p { ... }` or for grandparent and grandchild with `:not(.obox) > * > p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my interpretation of the question, it seems like you'd like to apply `color: #fff` to all `<p>` elements within `.dark-view` that are not a descendent of a `.obox` element. If this is the case, consider using the selector `.dark-view p:not(.obox *)`:

```css
p {
  color: #111;
}

.dark-view p:not(.obox *) {
  color: #fff;
}

/* irrelevant demo stuff */
.dark-view {
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

.obox {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dark-view">
  
  <div class="obox">
    <p>default</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="obox">
      <p>default</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="obox">
        <p>default</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <p>ondark</p>
  <div>
    <p>ondark</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>default</p>

<div class="dark-view">
  <p>ondark</p>
  <div>
    <p>ondark</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>ondark</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. I didn't know we could use the :not() selector like this.

Answer (score 0):

Although Wongjn's answer does exactly what I wanted, I've found a cleaner solution with CSS variables.
The benefit of this is that I don't end up with a long list of :not() selectors everywhere when multiple items should be resetting the color back to it's original value. Instead I'll only need to add them to the root selector

```css
:root, .obox {
  --text-color: #111;
}

.dark-view {
  --text-color: white;
}

p {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

/* irrelevant demo stuff */
.dark-view {
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

.obox {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dark-view">
  
  <div class="obox">
    <p>default</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="obox">
      <p>default</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="obox">
      <div>
        <p>default</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <p>ondark</p>
  <div>
    <p>ondark</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>default</p>

<div class="dark-view">
  <p>ondark</p>
  <div>
    <p>ondark</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>ondark</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```